# What does "blocked=-2" mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to create an index on a pretty big table (over 8 million rows).

The index creation was taking over 10 minutes, so I selected from `master..sysprocesses` from my process spid:

```
spid    kpid    blocked waittype    waittime    lastwaittype    waitresource        dbid    uid cpu physical_io memusage    login_time                  last_batch              ecid    open_tran   status      sid             hostname        program_name                                    hostprocess     cmd             nt_domain   nt_username     net_address     net_library loginame    context_info    sql_handle  stmt_start  stmt_end    request_id
62      11836   -2      0x0003      11762       LCK_M_S         TAB: 5:427148567:0  5       1   0   0           3           2016-01-03 10:03:39.217     2016-01-03 10:15:41.013 0       1           suspended   0x010500...     MyPC            Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query  9636            CREATE INDEX    MyDom       Saul            xxx             LPC         MyDom\Saul  0x000...        0x0100...   522         776         0
```

What is that "blocked = -2"?  Why is my index creation not working?  And how do I repair this?

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in [sys.sysprocesses (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx):

[image: Excerpt]

You can find more information and possible actions to take in the duplicate question:

- [Dealing with Negative Session ID Denials in SQL Server](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2013/11/21/negative-session-id.aspx)
- [How It Works: Orphan DTC Transaction (Session/SPID = -2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/04/20/how-it-works-orphan-dtc-transaction-session-spid-2.aspx)
- [Orphaned MSDTC transactions](http://www.eraofdata.com/orphaned-msdtc-transactions-2-spids/)

In some cases, after proper investigation, it may be appropriate to configure SQL Server to presume that any in-doubt distributed transactions have aborted, using [`sp_configure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179586.aspx).